# Modal not reducing size on small screens

Tags: html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, grid

Using create-react-app fyi. I have this modal package I used from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-modal. It states that it is responsive.

I implemented it correctly and imported "react-responsive-modal/styles.css"; to make sure it is responsive. But when on mobile my content gets cut off and the modal doesn't minimize, I'm using CSS grid. Am I not calling something correctly? What I'm hoping to achieve is the modal keeps reducing in size as screens get smaller.

Grid CSS

```
      .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, auto));
      grid-gap: 5rem;
      margin-top: 2rem;
      justify-items: center;
      align-items: center;
}
.item {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<Modal>
 <img scr="/myimage.png" />
</Modal>
```

Comment: It could be the grid that's causing the issue. Have you tried using a flexbox instead? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ Hard to tell what's happening without a reproducible example of your code but that would be my first guess.

Comment: So instead of Css Grid I should use flexbox? You can view my site at ordacreatives.vercel.app

Comment: This is purely an opinion thing which probably goes against SO rules, _but_ I think a Flexbox is generally going to provide better results and be easier to work with when designing for responsive intent. Try changing your code and seeing if it gets you what you're looking for and we can always assist you if you run into an issue.  

If you're absolutely intent on using a grid, please consider updating your original post with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can further dissect your code.